# My string breaks into multiple line in my console.log but does not in my html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array, which I have converted into a string. I have added a line break which is picked up by the console, I would like to have this printed into my html using `document.getElementByID` but the html picks up the literal string rather than the line break. The code:

```
data = ["name 1: Bob", "name 2: Steve"]
var dataLined = data.toString().replace(',','<br/>')
console.log(dataLined)

document.getElementByID('Content').append("Data\n" + dataLined)
```

The console returns exactly what I want:

```
name 1: Steve
name 2: Bob
```

however, in my html I get

```
name 1: Steve<br/>name 2: Bob
```

As it appears to printing the literal string (as I've replace the comma with `<br/>`).

There may be a better way to print this to multiple lines, but this is what I've seen from similar queries on here. Does anyone know if there is a way I can print to the html without the `<br/>` there? Many thanks.

Comment: I have also tried '/n' instead of '<br/>' and '<br />' as I've seen them on here but to no avail.

Comment: var dataLined = data.toString().replace(',','\n');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out by editing the CSS to:

`white-space: pre-wrap`

this allows `\n` to be picked up by the html.

So I changed my code to:

```
data = ["name 1: Bob", "name 2: Steve"]
var dataLined = data.toString().replace(',','\n')
console.log(dataLined)

document.getElementByID('Content').append("Data\n" + dataLined)
```

Thanks to those that are maybe in progress of helping!

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because you are adding 
 into string. You need to do something like this:

```
data = ["name 1: Bob", "name 2: Steve"];
let list = document.querySelector("ul");
data.forEach(item => {
  let parts = item.split(": ");
  let elm = document.createElement("li");
  let text = document.createTextNode(`${parts[0]}: ${parts[1]}`);
  elm.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(elm);
})
```